# What is happening in this anonymous inner class & instance variable access situation?

Tags: java, android, junit, anonymous-inner-class

I'm trying to figure out the specifics of what's happening in the following situation:

I'm writing a test for the following callback in TestClass. (unless it's relevant, I'd vote to ignore the design decision of making things package visible :))

```
public class TestClass {

    Event mEvent;

    // omitted for the sake of brevity.

    EventsForDateLoader.Callback mEventsForDateLoadedCallback = new EventsForDateLoader.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCalendarEventsLoaded(List<CalendarEvent> calendarEvents) {
            mEvent.getEventDate(); // this results in a NPE
            // do other stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            // do stuff
        }
    };
}
```

For the test, I'm doing the following:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    test = new TestClass();
    test.mEvent = mock(Event.class);
}

@Test
public void testCallback_onCalendarEventsLoaded() {
    test.mEventsForDateLoadedCallback.onCalendarEventsLoaded(new ArrayList<>);
    // assert stuff
}
```

This test is failing as the mocked mEvent is null (mock is never set).

Why is this happening? I'd think the IDE would warn me if I was misusing an instance variable within the anonymous inner class.

In case this is of relevance, this is being done in an Android context.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a short but complete console app? (It looks okay to me...)

Comment: Ok, so this should work correctly? Must have a side effect somewhere else in my logic.

Comment: Can you confirm that it works without an NPE if you were to invoke `testCallback_onCalendarEventsLoaded` from the setup method? (as a sanity check...)

Comment: My guess is your test is not being run as a JUnit4-style test. Print something to `System.err` in the `@Before` method